# Fscanf doesn't storing value from file in variables in c

Tags: arrays, c, file, file-io, scanf

I'm trying to read value from file Balance.txt but fscanf is not storing any value ;

Thank you!! in advance!!

```
int bal[5];

//recipt generation
FILE *fp,*dp;
//reading balance
dp=fopen("Balance.txt","r"); 
fscanf(dp,"%d",bal[0]);
printf("%d\n",bal[0]);
```

Comment: Typo for `fscanf(dp,"%d",&bal[0]);`?

Comment: Or just `fscanf(dp,"%d", ba+0);`, which ultimately is `fscanf(dp,"%d",ba);`

Comment: Look at your compiler messages.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall`. The `fscanf` will be flagged by the compiler.

Comment: What the other comments are trying to say is this: Your compiler should have given you a warning like `format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument has type ‘int’`.  If it did not, it would be really good if you could use a newer/better compiler, or figure out how to enable more warnings with the one you're using.  Without basic warnings like these, learning C is going to be much harder and more frustrating than it ought to be.

Comment: for robust code, and to let the implementation help you, always check the returned value from system functions to assure the operation was successful.  Suggest reading the 'man' page for each system function you use

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here: `fscanf(dp,"%d",bal[0]);`

- you should pass the address of an `int`, not an `int` value.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int bal[5];

    //receipt generation
    FILE *fp, *dp;
    //reading balance
    dp = fopen("Balance.txt", "r");
    if (dp && fscanf(dp, "%d", &bal[0]) == 1) {
        printf("%d\n", bal[0]);
        ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```